# Combine multiple Yaxis in one

Tags: highcharts

is it possible to combine several yaxis into a single one as the picture below?

[image: Screenshot]

I know it's a little bit strange, but that's what I need to do. Thank you.

Comment: The picture is really hard to make out, and it only provides the axis; we can't see what the rest of the graph looks like in order to know how it interacts together.

Comment: I'm sorry It's the only thing I have, it's not Higcharts, it's a chart that puts all the series in on yaxis as you can see, the rest is like hogcharts.

Comment: "as you can see"  Well, no - the point is we can't really see.  I can't make out what is in the image at all...it's small, blurry, and pixelated.  Be more specific about what you want - "all on one y axis" can mean a lot of things.

Comment: Honestly I see only single yAxis, with a few color series, so where are others?

Comment: Hi all, I will try to get a better screen cap tomorrow. The idea is that there is a single yaxis for mutliple series. The library just plots all values for diferents series in the same yaxis but with diferent colors. Each one has his one scale. http://i.imgur.com/XH0EYDk.jpg

Comment: such a axis with multiple axes combined will create much havoc for user to understand, it will damage the user experience.

Comment: I agree, but it's an existing software feature that I need to replicate. Could I manually add the labels with they own value and color and dont use the yaxis values.

Comment: So you need to have many series and (in case when you need) set additinal yAxis with serie.

Comment: I want to do this as well, but i am unsure if it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to combine multiple y-axis in highcharts.

Please see [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)